# Calculate index of bottom left block on a mxn grid

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working on a board game that requires me to color the bottom left corner of the board with random number of rows and columns a different color from the other blocks. Given an m x n grid, how do I calculate the index of the bottom left block?
On a 4x4 block, the index is 12, on a 3x3 block the index 6, on a 2x2 block the index is 2, on a 3x4 block the index is 8, and on a 4x3 block the index is 9. Thank you in advance for the help!

I tried the following but it colors the top left box instead of the bottom left:

```
for(int r = 0; r < numRow; r++){
              for(int c=0; c < numCol; c++){
                  if(r==numRow-1 && c==0){
                      buttons[c].setBackground(new Color(250, 0, 0));
                      buttons[c].setEnabled(false);
                  }
              }
          }
```

Comment: Not the down vote, but this is more of a basic pattern computation than a game dev question. It also doesn't show what you've tried to do to work through the problem. Both of those tend to attract down votes.

Comment: [We have answered pattern computation questions here in the past](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/157291/39518), but I'd agree this one is very simple, and can probably be found answered on StackOverflow, since it follows from [the usual math to convert a 2D coordinate to a 1D index.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=2D+coordinates+to+index&searchOn=3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers in the leftmost column are all multiples of your column count. Taking your 4x3 case as an example:

```
0  1  2
3  4  5
6  7  8
9 10 11
```

The first row starts with zero, and each row after that is `numCol` more than the previous. So the leftmost number in the `n`th row is just `(n - 1)` times your column count:

```
int bottomLeft = numCol * (numRow - 1);
```

Draw a few tables of different sizes to convince yourself that this always matches the bottom-left number.